# A crazy but elegant solution to seamlessly update a hybrid app

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, mobile

I am using Phonegap to develop an mobile app.

Unlike web application, an mobile app is a static client which is updated less frequently than expected. Moreover, version management is required to maintain the dependency between server and client end.

I am thinking about a way to make the mobile app more like a pure browser. And here is a potential solution.

1. The initial index.html in Phonegap app gets the latest version from server and compares the version number cached in the browser/WebView;
2. If the current version is behind the latest, it fetches the remote homepage and replaces the whole html document and caches the latest version number;

Pros:

1. No more need to publish new version of mobile apps;
2. All platforms (mobile and web) use the latest version, no more manual update is required;

Cons:

1. Obvious delay when updating to new version, including the first launch;
2. All scripts and styles must be cached in localStorage to prevent browser from reloading these files unexpectedly.

I am sure some of you must have the same problem or idea. I will really appreciate if you share your thoughts here.

Comment: For me the trade-off would depend on how often the application would update, how large the application was, and if you could give the user some sort of visual feedback as to WHY the application is taking longer to load on an update.

I think your idea is a simple solution and it can be a good solution in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is a tool, such as finding nearby restaurants or calling for a delivery service, I believe some pages with fixed layout and styling will do. The functions should rarely be changed, right?

For example, you can have a page showing a Google Map with markers attached to it, indicating all the nearby restaurants. Whenever there are changes to the list of restaurants saved on the server, the client does not require any modifications, as long as the functionality of this page is kept the same as usual.

Think of the homepage of Google. There is always a toolbar at the top, a Google Doodle and a search bar underneath. The layout is almost always the same. What differs is the Doodle which is dynamically loaded. Having a fixed layout should save you from updating your app client too frequently.

By the way, I usually don't update the apps on my mobile phone, as I am too lazy to do so. Therefore, I agree with you that it is better to publish new versions as few as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I created a 1-way sync that updates my local web storage (SQLite) which is on just about every device these days. My sync updates my apps login/users it gets new updates from the db an updates my apps web storage.

You can use regular SQLite to write to your devices web storage that will only update when online.